# How to tell if a textbox is focused in the OS or not?

Tags: c#

I need to program a keyboard, with some configurations and customizations.
I need to configure it to be enabled if any text area is focused before the keyboard.
mainly I need to know what control is selected.

The Keyboard is a standalone application, so it cannot deal directly with the controls, just by accessing the OS.

for more explanation, I am gonna tell you the scenario:

1. the user runs the keyboard application, which its 'topmost' is set, and `ShowInTaskBar` is unset, and the keyboard is disabled.
2. the user clicks on any text control in the window, like the notepad or a TextBox in Microsoft Word or Paint, then after clicking the keyboard application is enabled.
3. the user clicks on the keyboard application and its keys to write text on the TextBox selected before in step 2, please note that the previous TextBox will loose focus but the keyboard will still enabled.

Comment: It sounds like maybe you want to be a client for [`UI Automation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753326.aspx). Unfortunately, it's quite a big topic, unsuitable for going into depth on SO. But it allows you to listen for focus events, interrogate the type of control, etc.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, thanks for providing me with the thing I need,, however, it is just as you said, it is a huge topic, and really my head started to blown away.. I will search more on the UI Automation. the example provided by the msdn worked properly, so I can get notified when the focus is changed, but still |I can't get more and more info
Thanks a lot, once it is done with I will post it

Comment: You don't need to worry too much about it. Though it is a subject of UI automation, what you require is a very simple thing and you should be able to do it with a little bit more effort.

Comment: @MurtuzaKabul, the problem is I cannot find that simple thing, all I have is integers, most of their values are zeros !! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy by searching for the caret position, since it should be larger than 0

```
    GUITHREADINFO lpgui = new GUITHREADINFO();
    IntPtr fore = GetForegroundWindow();
    uint tpid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(fore, IntPtr.Zero);
    lpgui.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(lpgui.GetType());
    bool flag = GetGUIThreadInfo(tpid, out lpgui);
    WINDOWINFO pwi = new WINDOWINFO();
    pwi.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(pwi.GetType());
    GetWindowInfo((IntPtr)lpgui.hwndCaret, ref pwi);

    if (flag)
    {
        if (!(lpgui.rcCaret.Location.X == 0 && lpgui.rcCaret.Location.Y == 0))
        {


            //TODO

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `Focused property`

```
foreach (var control in this.Controls)
{
    if (control.Focused)
    {
          ....
        }
}
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.control.focused.aspx

Comment: That works if you're running within the same application. The OP has indicated that their application is looking for focus occurring inside e.g. Word or Paint.

Answer (score 0):

You will need two of the windows API function

GetActiveWindow(void);
GetWindowClass()

First will give you the active windows (Focussed window) and the second one will let you know if it is a text window or not.

You will need further functions sendmessage(...) to get the current text of the window and also to set the text.

It is more about windows API.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I have used this
'[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();'
but GetActiveWindow always returns a zero value, 
I don't know how to deal with these stuff very well, I am new at APIs and hooks.
Thanks a lot

Comment: You don't need to use hooks, just the apis. I would suggest that you go to pinvoke.net and find out proper declarations of the function. It may happen quite a lot that you face issues with api as the .net types and api types are different. Further, API take a different approach for dealing with things. You will find that api functions have input as well as output parameters and most of the time, the return value will indicate either success or failure. - so keep on trying.